# How $this can refer to an instance of yii\web\View class in layouts files in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Documentation comments in yii2 say us that `$this` pointer in layout files refer to `yii\web\View`, but I'm confused that how this pointer can used outside of his class!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug the code deep enough, you will see this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/View.php#L341

They require a file in the method, that is why `$this` point to class :)